# mod_python unable to locate the web.py module under a virtual environment

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, web.py

I have a small `web.py` Python application that I would like to serve under Apache using `mod_python`.  The `web.py` framework, as well as other third-party Python modules the application in question relies upon, are installed in a virtual environment.  The virtual environment is created inside:  `/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/`

The relevant snippet from the virtual host configuration for Apache that I am using in order to set up this application is this:

```
<Location "/api">
    PythonPath "['/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/lib/python2.5/site-packages/', '/home/ayaz/project/'] + sys.path"
    #PythonHandler wsgiref.modpython_gateway::handler
    PythonHandler modpython_gateway::handler
    SetHandler python-program 
    PythonOption wsgi.application device_api::main
    PythonOption device_api /api/
</Location>
```

On the browser when I try to access the `/api` URL however, I get a `500` from the server with the error in the logs saying that the `web` module imported from within the `device_api.py` file (which is my application) could not be found; in other words, I see an `ImportError`.  I am not sure why it is unable to find the `web` module.

I know that the `PythonPath` directive is working, at least *partially*, judging from the fact that the Python interpreter is able to find the `device_api.py` file from the path defined in that directive.  But, it is unable to find the rest of the modules for which the path is also defined in the same directive.

Any help with this will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

> **UPDATE #1**
>
> [Ned's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384946/mod-python-unable-to-locate-the-web-py-module-under-a-virtual-environment/4391234#4391234) had me looking
>   through the `site-packages` directory
>   for the virtual environment I have. 
>   While the permissions looked fine
>   inside the directory to me, I realized
>   that `mod_python/Apache` was not able
>   to read the `eggs`.  Since I installed
>   all the packages inside the virtual
>   environment using `easy_install`, they are all in the forms
>   of eggs. So, for example, if I moved
>   the directory
>   `/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/lib/python2.5/site-packages/web.py-0.34-py2.5.egg/web/`
>   into
>   `/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/lib/python2.5/site-packages/`
>   (essentially taking it out of the egg
>   file/directory), `mod_python` stopped
>   complaining about the missing `web`
>   module (of course, it then started
>   complaining about the missing rest of
>   the third-party modules).
>
> I have Apache configured to run as my
>   user and group, that is `ayaz`, and I
>   checked that the permissions on the
>   `/home/ayaz/.python-eggs` directory
>   were fine.
>
> I then used this [Using eggs with
>   mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#using-eggs-with-mod-python) tricked explained on
>   the Django deployment documentation
>   page.  But it didn't help. 
>   Eventually, I bit the bullet, and for
>   each third-party module that
>   `mod_python` complained it couldn't
>   find, I moved the actual directory
>   from inside the egg for that module
>   outside of the egg and into the
>   `site-packages` directory for the
>   virtual environment. This made
>   `mod_python` find the modules.
>
> Now, I am really not sure why this
>   is happening, and why `mod_python` isn't
>   able to read through the eggs.

Comment: Note that mod_python is dead and that you are advised to migrate to mod_wsgi at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Hi Ignacio.  Thanks for the comment.  I realize that.  But I have some constraints, and I would very much like to get it to work under `mod_python` for the time being at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as to answer this question, I am going to copy the update paragraphs from my question and post them as the answer (as they seem to explain to some extent how I manage to get rid of the problem).

> [Ned's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384946/mod-python-unable-to-locate-the-web-py-module-under-a-virtual-environment/4391234#4391234) had me looking through the
>   site-packages directory for the
>   virtual environment I have. While the
>   permissions looked fine inside the
>   directory to me, I realized that
>   mod_python/Apache was not able to read
>   the eggs. Since I installed all the
>   packages inside the virtual
>   environment using easy_install, they
>   are all in the forms of eggs. So, for
>   example, if I moved the directory
>   `/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/lib/python2.5/site-packages/web.py-0.34-py2.5.egg/web/`
>   into
>   `/home/ayaz/Sandbox/Scrapper/lib/python2.5/site-packages/`
>   (essentially taking it out of the egg
>   file/directory), mod_python stopped
>   complaining about the missing web
>   module (of course, it then started
>   complaining about the missing rest of
>   the third-party modules).
>
> I have Apache configured to run as my
>   user and group, that is ayaz, and I
>   checked that the permissions on the
>   `/home/ayaz/.python-eggs` directory were
>   fine.
>
> I then used this [Using eggs with
>   mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#using-eggs-with-mod-python) tricked explained on the
>   Django deployment documentation page.
>   But it didn't help. Eventually, I bit
>   the bullet, and for each third-party
>   module that mod_python complained it
>   couldn't find, I moved the actual
>   directory from inside the egg for that
>   module outside of the egg and into the
>   site-packages directory for the
>   virtual environment. This made
>   mod_python find the modules.
>
> Now, I am really not sure why this is
>   happening, and why mod_python isn't
>   able to read through the eggs.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a file or directory permission problem?  Verify that the all of the files and directories in your `virtualenv` `site-packages` are accessible from the user name that `Apache` and `mod_python` are running under.

Comment: Thank you, Ned, for you answer. It has helped me uncover something. I've updated the question with further information.